# What are some effective methods of documenting packet protocols?

Tags: c#, networking, documentation

I'm working with a few developers on a hobby project and we have a lot of different APIs. What are some popular methods of creating documentation on the potential requests, and what can be expected to be returned? Is there any fancy automatic generation tools for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how RFCs are done. Here's one for the client-side [IRC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812) protocol.

There is no set standard but [Backus-Naur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) form (and extensions) are widely used. The upside of using BNF is that there exist tools that will output the code that obeys the protocol.

This means that instead of doing Manual C# => Autogenerated Document protocol, you could do Manual Document Protocol => Autogenerated C# code.